# Using two verbs with respectively

Tags: verbs

I would like to know which one is correct?

1. Sara and Jack buy and use a car and a bicycle, respectively.
2. Sara and Jack buys and uses a car and a bicycle, respectively.

Please note that the original sentences are:

> Sara buys a car and Jack uses a bicycle.

So, each verb is for one person.

Answer (score 1):

> (1) Sara and Jack buy and use a car and a bicycle, respectively.
>   (2) Sara and Jack buys and uses a car and a bicycle, respectively.

(2) is ungrammatical: it can only be parsed as conjunct (and hence plural) subjects with conjunct singular verbs.

(1) is grammatical, but it doesn't mean what you intend. That *respectively* distributes the immediately preceding conjunct term, *a car and a bicycle* between the two subjects, so what it says is that

> Sara buys and uses a car, and Jack buys and uses a bicycle

Since what you mean is that Sara buys a car and Jack uses a bicycle, you'll have to find another way of distributing the conjunct verbs, such as:

> Sara buys, and Jack uses, a car and a bicycle, respectively.

Both of these are grammatically acceptable; but I urge you to restrict their actual use to homework assignments and examination essays where you want to demonstrate your mastery of old-fashioned syntactic ingenuities. The use of "respectively" and complicated distributions makes your sentences difficult to parse, which is a discourtesy to your reader; in many cases it doesn't even save keystrokes. Say things as simply as possible:

> Sara buys a car and Jack uses a bicycle.

Comment: The last one is perfect